# PHP and mySql user uploading script

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best way of creating an upload script where the user can see all of the files he creates? I'll be using a sql database, I don't want a table for every person, unless I mean, it's okay.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I wrote this question in a hurry. I currently have a login system, where each user has a unique id. I assume it would be more efficient to make a new table for each user and store the files they upload in that table, rather than have a single table for all users.

My question is, is this a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique id for each user and insert it into the row witht he upload data. To view all of a users upload SELECT the uploads that match the unique ID.

Comment: Okay, I was originally thinking that. But lets say miraculously I get a large user database, how slow would it be? For example, what's the difference between searching through 100 entries and 10,000 entries?

Comment: Hi,this is exactly what database have been built for. It will be quite a while until you have this problem and then there are ways